# CSS. Почему не схлопываются margin-ы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Пример:

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container_standart_menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.li_menu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="site_menu container_standart_menu">
    <li class="li_menu li_active">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#home">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#about">ОБО МНЕ</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#service">УСЛУГИ</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu"><a class="animated_link" href="#portfolio">ПОРТФОЛИО</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#contacts">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Почему у элементов `<li>`, `margin` не схлопываются?
Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вот статейка про отступы во флех-контейнерах... https://habr.com/ru/articles/468327/

Answer (score 0):

У списка стоит свойство display: flex, из за этого нет схлопывания.
Установите значение block

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container_standart_menu{
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
}
.li_menu{
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 18px; 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  transition: 0.2s color; 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="site_menu container_standart_menu" >
      <li class="li_menu li_active" ><a class="animated_link" href="#home">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li> 
      <li class="li_menu" ><a class="animated_link" href="#about">ОБО МНЕ</a></li> 
      <li class="li_menu" ><a class="animated_link" href="#service">УСЛУГИ</a></li> 
      <li class="li_menu" ><a class="animated_link" href="#portfolio">ПОРТФОЛИО</a></li> 
      <li class="li_menu"><a class="animated_link" href="#contacts">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li> 
  </ul> 
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать так чтобы при display flex margin-ы также схлопывались?

Comment: @Shillkas, У флексов нет схлопывания margin. Если вам нужен отступ в 10px исправьте ваш css.

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container_standart_menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.li_menu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s color;
}

.li_menu:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.li_menu:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site_menu container_standart_menu">
  <li class="li_menu li_active"><a class="animated_link" href="#home">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
  <li class="li_menu"><a class="animated_link" href="#about">ОБО МНЕ</a></li>
  <li class="li_menu"><a class="animated_link" href="#service">УСЛУГИ</a></li>
  <li class="li_menu"><a class="animated_link" href="#portfolio">ПОРТФОЛИО</a></li>
  <li class="li_menu"><a class="animated_link" href="#contacts">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

- ополовинить отступы у детей
- добавить поля у родителя

```css
/* Styles go here */

.container_standart_menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.li_menu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s color;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="site_menu container_standart_menu">
    <li class="li_menu li_active">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#home">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#about">ОБО МНЕ</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#service">УСЛУГИ</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu"><a class="animated_link" href="#portfolio">ПОРТФОЛИО</a></li>
    <li class="li_menu">
      <a class="animated_link" href="#contacts">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```